# How Do I Use Column Value in Window Function for a Dynamic Frame with Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm not sure if this is possible with Postgres, but I would like each row to compute its window function "frame".

So how would I use a column from the current row as an argument to `ROWS` in a window function with Postgres?

For instance..

```
create table items (
  id serial primary key, name varchar, price integer, precede_by integer
);

insert into items (name, price, precede_by) 
  values 
  ('A', 1, 2), ('A', 1, 3), 
  ('B', 1, 1),('B',1, 2), ('B', 1, 1), ('B', 2, 2), 
  ('C', 1, 2), ('C', 1,2), ('C', 1, 2), ('C', 1, 5);
```

I would like to use the integer value set in the `precede_by` column.. E.g., something like this..

```
select name, sum(price) over 
  (partition by name rows between precede_by preceding and current row) 
from items;
```

But this doesn't work. I receive `ERROR:  argument of ROWS must not contain variables`

Comment: you miss the `order by` as well, what is the ordering for one `name`?

Comment: I don't really care about how they are ordered.. in this example I'm just curious about how to use value from row for a dynamic window function frame. Does `order by` help solve that?

Comment: @seanb123 It doesn't help solve that, no. But... your results will be nonsense without it (assuming you crack the variable nut here).

Comment: Also, having a column that suggests there is a relationship between your current record and some other records that are ordered previous to the current record seems like not-so-great design. It's suggesting that there is some inherent ordering to records in a table, which there isn't. It seems like maybe a category_id or a parent/child relationship would be more appropriate here to group your records. So you can just `sum(price) .. group by category_id` or do some maths in a recursive CTE (if it's more hiearchical in nature). Perhaps you share your desired results given your sample data though

Comment: This is just a simple example in an attempt to isolate the problem. I am interested in a dynamic window function frame using a column from current row. Not interested in what the sums actually are.

Comment: Also sub selects seem to work.. in window functions.. e.g, `select name, sum(price) over 
  (partition by name order by name rows between (select precede_by from items order by random() limit 1) preceding and current row) 
from items` but still not able to get at column from current row.

Comment: Please view [Bruce Momjian's presentation](http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/window.pdf) it helped to me, so maybe it can help you too.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to write the window function as you want. I believe that `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` can do the trick

```
with oitems as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) rn from items
)
select * 
from oitems i1
cross join lateral 
(
  select sum(price) 
  from  oitems i2
  where i1.name = i2.name and i2.rn >= i1.rn - i1.precede_by and i2.rn <= i1.rn
) t
```

and another (maybe more elegant) solution is to just use self-join with `GROUP BY`

```
with oitems as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) rn from items
)
select i1.id, i1.name, i1.price, sum(i2.price) 
from oitems i1
join  oitems i2 on i1.name = i2.name and i2.rn >= i1.rn - i1.precede_by and i2.rn <= i1.rn
group by i1.id, i1.name, i1.price
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=29b910e2d14e85e39c72c0d4290a41e0)

Comment: Yes, this works to accomplish what I'm ultimately after.. Thanks! But doesn't solve the dynamic frame w/in a window function. But I like this solution as I don't know if what I'm hoping to achieve w/ window functions is even possible.  Thank you.